# How to get the error "Error converting data type nvarchar to int." by try catch statement in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to input two values (int, nvarchar)  into a table.

I also have to handle error during this process by getting the error messages printed in a text file.

For testing purposes, I entered `varchar` value in the int parameter, and vice  versa. But that error could not be caught by catch block.

Try block is working perfectly, I am getting the message in my log.

Here is my code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertInTesting] 
    (@i INT, @nm NVARCHAR(50))     
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @num int
        SET @num = 5/0

        INSERT INTO dbo.testing (id, name) 
        VALUES (@i, @nm) 

        EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo Successfully inserted --%time%-- -- %date%--   >>H:\log.txt'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @Command varchar(512), @text varchar(300)
        SET @text = Error_message() +'--%time%-- -- %date%-- ';
        SET @Command = 'echo "'+@text+'" >>H:\log.txt'
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling the SP by passing the wrong input, SQL will throw error before entering into your `TRY` block itself, this is the reason your **`CATCH`** is not catching the invalid input parameter error. Your `CATCH` will only catch those errors which are happening inside your `TRY` block.

If you want all your error to be catched you need to call the SP as follwong (If you are calling it from SQL server).

```
 BEGIN try 
    EXEC [dbo].[insertInTesting]  'ABC','12'
  END try 
  BEGIN catch 
      --LOG YOUR ERROR
  END catch
```

In this case you will be able to catch the error like following.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure insertInTesting, Line 0 [Batch
>   Start Line 17] Error converting data type varchar to int.

In case if you are calling your SP from some other tool, you need to implement `TRY CATCH` there.